# Oracle SQL function similar to RANK

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I wondering if there is a ***single*** Oracle function that will give me the lowest rank among ties (THIS column in image below) instead of the highest rank. I know I can take the output of RANK and derive what I'm looking for. I'm just wondering if I'm overlooking another function or function option. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `range between` qualifier:

```
with t as (
      select 10 as score from dual union all
      select 20 from dual union all
      select 20 from dual union all
      select 30 from dual
     )
select t.*, rank() over (order by score),
       count(*) over (order by score range between unbounded preceding and current row)
from t;
```

I prefer to be explicit but the default for `order by` with no window clause is `range between` (I think this is ANSI standard behavior, true on the four databases I tested on), so you can remove it:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by score),
       count(*) over (order by score)
from t;
```

Comment: After trying to understand the RANGE BETWEEN qualifier, I see that COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY score) also works and is a little simpler to understand. But thank you for getting me on the right path.